# Why does Python refuse to execute this code in a new subprocess?

Tags: python, concurrency, compilation, subprocess

I am trying to make a very simple application that allows for people to define their own little python scripts within the application. I want to execute the code in a new process to make it easy to kill later. Unfortunately, Python keeps giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/skylion/Documents/python_exec test.py", line 19, in <module>
    code_process = Process(target=exec_, args=(user_input_code))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._args = tuple(args)
TypeError: 'code' object is not iterable
>>>
```

My code is posted below

```
user_input_string = '''
import os
world_name='world'
robot_name='default_body + os.path.sep'
joint_names=['hingejoint0', 'hingejoint1', 'hingejoint2', 'hingejoint3', 'hingejoint4', 'hingejoint5', 'hingejoint6', 'hingejoint7', 'hingejoint8']
print(joint_names)
'''

def exec_(arg):
    exec(arg)
user_input_code = compile(user_input_string, 'user_defined', 'exec') 
from multiprocessing import Process
code_process = Process(target=exec_, args=(user_input_code))
code_process.start()
```

What am I missing? Is there something wrong with my user_input_string? With my compile options? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `args` must be a tuple. To create a single-element tuple, add a comma like so: `args=(user_input_code,)`